# How do I specify arguments and streams for processes created in Mono?

Tags: c#, linux, unix, mono

I want to start a process from a Mono application on a Unix-like system, specifying command-line arguments and file descriptors.

For example, this includes things like:

- Redirecting stdout and stderr to the same fdes
- Redirecting stdout to a pipe, and connecting the other end of the pipe to another process's stdin
- Redirecting an fdes > 2 (not stdin, stdout, stderr)

These basic Unix features seem to have no support whatsoever in Mono.

- `System.Diagnostics.Process` is designed for use on Windows systems, since it only permits arguments to be passed as a single string, and has no provision for redirecting output to specific pipes or files.  It also seems reckless to quote and unquote strings just to get from my code to a system call.
- [`Mono.Unix.UnixProcess`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aMono.Unix.UnixProcess) seems to lack any ability to create new processes.
- [`Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aMono.Unix.Native.Syscall%2fM) only has an `execve()` method, no `fork()` method, which is understandable, but it still leaves me high and dry.

So, how do I make this happen?  It seems like my only option is to write a program in C which does what I want and then invoke that program from Mono, but that seems like a rather convoluted way to accomplish something that only requires a few lines of code in languages like C or Python.

Comment: Do you mean something like running your process in this way by means of System.Diagnostics.Process?: `your_process argument1 argument2 /your/chosen/stdout /your/chosen/stdin` (redirecting to file descriptors). Also, do you know these properties?: [RedirectStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [RedirectStandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Gooseman: How do I redirect standard output to a pipe?  `RedirectStandardOutput` is just a `bool`, it doesn't let me specify *where* I want to redirect it.  Also, what if the arguments contain backslashes or spaces?  I would rather not have to deal with that, since the underlying syscall specifies the arguments as separate strings anyway.  The `System.Diagnostics.Process` interface seems truly terrible.